# OCR on image - iOS

Tags: ios, ocr, microblink, anyline

Is it possible to perform OCR on image (for example, from assets) instead of live video with Anyline, microblink or other SDKs?

Tesseract is not an option due to my limited time.

I've tested it but the results are very inappropriate. I know that it can be improved with OpenCv or something but I have to keep a deadline.

**EDIT:**

This is an example of what the image looks like when it arrives to the *OCR SDK*.[image: this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure for the others, but you can use microblink SDK for reading from a single image. It is documented [here](https://github.com/blinkinput/blinkinput-ios/wiki/Direct-processing-API).

Reading from a video stream will give much better results, but it all depends on what you are trying to do exactly. What are you trying to read?

For reading barcodes or MRZ from i.e. identity documents, it works pretty well. For raw text OCR, not quite as good but it is not really intended for that anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to have a look át the documentation a bit later. I'm trying to read random personal codes to identify the person. But First I process the image to find those badges, crop the image around them and make tracking later.

Comment: So, I read the documentation and I think that is what I'm looking for. But I have a problem. After I call *coordinator.processImage* I get no results at all. *didStartRecognition*, *didStartDetection* and *didFinishRecognition* methods are called but *didObtainResult* not. I've attached an example image to my question.

Comment: I've found the problem. The documentation is a bit outdated and I some classes do not exists. But I found the solution in the example project. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR
Machine learning based, Trainable on different font, chars, etc.
and free